# Ember: When child controllers are observing same property of Parent controller firing request simultaneously

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have created an application with two child object controller and a parent array controller. The route is also described in the same way.

```js
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.extend(function() {
  this.resource('parent', function() {
    this.route('child1', {
      path: '/'
    });
    this.route('child2');
  });
});

var ParenteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    //Got my model from here.
  };
});

var Child1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.$.ajax('dummyUrl.com');
  },
  action:{
    refreshData: function(){
      var controller = this.controllerFor('parent.child1');
      return Ember.$.ajax('dummyUrl.com').then(function(response){
        return controller.send('updateModel' response);
      });
    }
  }
});

var ParentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  getFirstName: function() {
    return this.get('model').get('firstName');
  },
  getLastName: function() {
    return this.get('model').get('lastName');
  }
});

var Child1Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['ParentController'],
  getName: function() {
    return this.get('controllers.ParentController.getFirstName')
  },
  updateName: function() {
    this.send('refreshData');
  }.observes('controllers.ParentController.getLastName'),
  actions: {
    updateModel: function(response) {
      this.set('getName', response);
    }
  }
});

var Child2Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['ParentController'],
  getFirstName: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.ParentController.getFirstName')
});
```

```html
<!--Parent Template--!>
<div>
<input type='text' {{bind-attr value=getFirstName}}>
<input type='text' {{bind-attr value=getLastName}}>
</div>
{{#link-to 'parent.child1'}}child1{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'parent.child2'}}child2{{/link-to}}
{{outlet}}

<!--child1 template--!>

<div>
  {{getName}}
</div>

<!--child2 template--!>

<div>
  {{getFirstName}}
</div>
```

So the problem with the above code is that when I am in the index of parent controller then on change of getLastName property every time child1's function updateName() is called and is executed properly. But after doing some changes while keeping child1 route active if a move to child2's route by clicking on the link to, then when I change the property getLastName, though I am in child2, child1's updateName() function is also getting triggered because of the observes function and throwing the error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'refreshData'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
```

I need help in understanding how I can tackle this problem. And is this method of reloading the model in a child up on a change in the parent controller's property is a good way, if not then please suggest the right way of doing it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: First when I am in child1 route I try to refresh or reload my model as per the changes made in the getLastName property of the parent. Where as in second one I am just showing the getFirstName property of the parent. But when I move from Child1 route to child2 route, the refreshData method is called even though I being in child2 route and that is throwing the action not handled error, I believe it is to do something with observers being set on the refreshData method.

Comment: I basically don't want the observers to trigger when I am in a different child route.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want properties to update in different templates. You need to try to think about Ember in terms of managing objects (models) instead of the properties of those objects. With Ember's bindings, the properties should update automatically. You'll want to look into using the [store](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) to manage said objects.

You don't really anything in `ParentController`. You can just use the model from `ParentRoute` directly in your template, e.g.

```
<div>
  {{input value=model.firstName}}
  {{input value=model.lastname}}
</div>
{{#link-to 'parent.child1'}}child1{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'parent.child2'}}child2{{/link-to}}
{{outlet}}
```

then your child controllers become much simpler:

```
App.Child1Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['ParentController'],
  parentModel: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.ParentController.model')
});

App.Child2Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['ParentController'],
  parentModel: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.ParentController.model')
```

});

and you'd use them in your templates like so:

```
<div>
  {{parentModel.firstName}}
</div>
```

Comment: I Understand what you mean to say but I need to refresh and get totally different data via service call up on change of the lastName of the parent controller property in the first child. So I came up with that code. And so only I put up the observer on the updateName method of the child1 controller. But when I move to Child 2 controller I don't want that kind of scenario. I do know that due to Ember's observer tag on the updateName method, it will get fired whether or not it is the active route, what I do want to know is whether there is any other way to avoid it and get what I desire in Ember